# bash: is it safe to use file as input to next command right after outputting to it?

Tags: bash

If I output to a file

```
somecommand > somefile
```

is it okay to pass `somefile` as input argument to a command right on the next line? will it always execute only after the file has been completely written or do I need to do something to make sure this is safe?

Comment: Yes it's totally safe unless your operating system, shell or "next command" is broken. You can of course always come with counter-examples like "what if the next command is `dd oflag=direct ...`?, etc" -- but better narrow down the question to your actual problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to use it in the next command if the previous one has ended. If you are using commands one by one and all of them run in the foreground (it's true unless you specifically do otherwise), you can trust your system to handle the rest. Even if the file wasn't really written to the disk and was still residing in a cache, your OS will handle the situation transparently for you.

Just a remark: in some situations you can be better off without even using a file as a place for some intermediate result. If the only use for output of a program is to feed the next one, you can pipe:

`dmesg | grep eth0 | less`

Answer (score 0):

### You Can Safely Read from a Closed File

You can do this safely:

```
somecommand > somefile
sort somefile
```

without any problems. However, you can't generally read from the same file you're writing to without an intermediate step or utility. For example:

```bsh
echo foo >  words
echo bar >> words

# This will clobber the file you're
# reading from. Don't do it!
sort < words > words
```

### When You Need to Read and Write the Same File

There are many ways to deal with this common need. For example, the *sponge* utility from the moreutils package will allow you to do this safely:

```
echo foo >  words
echo bar >> words

# sponge is like tee, but soaks up all the input
# from the pipe before writing to your output file
sort words | sponge words

# your words are now sorted:
#   bar
#   foo
cat words
```